# Vue, how to create component without template?

Tags: vue.js

The following functionality is needed, after user authorization, it returns back to the application via a link with a callback function - localhost / callback, at this point I don't need to render anything, the application parses information in the search bar and the router pushes to the user's page, but vue swears that there is no template for rendering, how to implement this functionality correctly?
[image]

my callback code:

```
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useUserStore } from '../../../stores/userState'

export default {
    name: 'AuthCallback',
    setup() {
        const tokenParseRegex: RegExp = /access_token=(.*?)&/;
        const idParseRegex: RegExp = /user_id=(.*?)$/;
        const exAccessToken: RegExpMatchArray | null = useRoute().hash.match(tokenParseRegex);
        const exUserId: RegExpMatchArray | null = useRoute().hash.match(idParseRegex);
        if (exAccessToken !== null) {
            useUserStore().userAccess.accessToken = exAccessToken![1];
            useUserStore().userAccess.userId = exUserId![1];
            useUserStore().userAccess.isAuthorized = true;
            localStorage.setItem('userAccess', JSON.stringify(useUserStore().userAccess))
        } else {
            useRouter().push({
                name: 'AuthFailed',
            })
        }
        if (exUserId) {
            useRouter().push({
                name: 'UserInit',
                params: { usedId: String(exUserId![1]) },
            })
        } else {
            useRouter().push({
                name: 'AuthFailed',
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your logic in a router [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

```
{
  path: '/callback',
  component: {},
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    const isSuccessfulAuth = checkSomething()

    if (isSuccessfulAuth) {
      next({
        name: 'UserInit',
      })
    } else {
      next({
        name: 'AuthFailed',
      })
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just remebmered a better way (if your logic is synchronous). You can create a [redirect](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) route

```
{
  path: '/callback',
  redirect: () => {
    const isSuccessfulAuth = checkSomething()

    if (isSuccessfulAuth) {
      return {
        name: 'UserInit',
      }
    } else {
      return {
        name: 'AuthFailed',
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: when trying to use ur both methods, getting this error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hash')
In this -
const exAccessToken: RegExpMatchArray | null = useRoute().hash.match(tokenParseRegex);
How to fix it?

Comment: To get the route object use beforeEach() or redirect() first parameter instead of useRoute(). `redirect: (route) => { route.hash.match... }` or `beforeEach: (to, from, next) => { to.hash.match... }`

Comment: Yep, all works, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A component needs to have either a template or a render function defined. With that said, you can take a look at [renderless components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#renderless-components) or [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables).

However, I think it would be simpler to put this logic into state management solution like [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/), where you can handle everything about authentication, and call it from App component or "Callback" page when it mounts.

Edit:

You can also combine it with [@Romalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11208064/romalex)'s solution. That is, use store in the navigation guard.

```js
{
    path: '/callback',
    component: {},
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        const authStore = useAuthStore();

        authStore.checkToken(...); // use extracted parts from regexes
        
        if(isSuccessfulAuth) {
            next({
                name: 'UserInit',
            })
        } else {
            next({
                name: 'AuthFailed'
            })
        }
    }
}
```